# Searching two tables with one query

Tags: sql, sqlite

When searching in sqlite, I search all columns once using the following SQL:

```
Select id from table where '--' || IFNULL(name, ' ')  
|| '--' || IFNULL(created, ' ')  || '--' || IFNULL(desc, ' ')  
|| '--' LIKE '%query%'
```

Now I need to search an `order` table and the `order details` table. They look like so

**Order table**

```
id
date
customer_id
```

**order_details**

```
id
product_id
cost
orders_id
qty
```

How do I search in this case, I tried using a join:

```
Select o.id,o.customer_id from orders o where '--' 
(Select * from customers where name like '%query%' and id=customer_id) '--' 
||  (Select * from product where name like '%query%' and ID =
(Select product_id from order_details where id =odetails_id)) '--' LIKE '%query%'
```

**EDIT**

I tried this new query , but i got an error saying at 'OR'

```
SELECT o.id FROM orders o WHERE o.id in

((SELECT order_id FROM order_items WHERE order_items.service_id In
(SELECT id FROM services WHERE name like query))  
OR o.id in
(SELECT order_id FROM order_items WHERE order_items.customer_id In
(SELECT id FROM customers WHERE name like query)) 
OR o.id in
(SELECT order_id FROM order_items WHERE order_items.cloth_id In
(SELECT id FROM cloths WHERE name like query) ))
```

How do i fix this

Comment: Isn't it missing a `order_details.order_id`? And what is your expected result?

Comment: @LS_dev thanks for pointing that out, i have to edit sensitive info away, but i added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query contains some errors:

1. Several || are missing
2. You are selecting * twice where a scalar value is expected

Assuming the missing tables to be as follows

```
create table product (id, name);
create table customers (id, name);
```

Your query can be fixed like this

```
Select o.id,o.customer_id 
from orders o 
where '--'  || 
      ( select name 
        from customers 
        where name like '%query%' and id=customer_id ) || 
  '--'  ||  
      ( select name 
        from product 
        where name like '%query%' and 
              id = ( select product_id 
                     from order_details 
                     where id =odetails_id ) ) || 
  '--' 
  LIKE '%query%';
```

However, I suggest that you replace your scalar subqueries by joins

```
select o.id, o.customer_id 
from orders o 
     join customers c on o.customer_id = c.id
     join order_details d on o.odetails_id = d.id
     join product p on d.product_id = p.id         
where c.name = '%query' and
      p.name = '%query' and
      '--' || c.name || '--' || p.name || '--' like '%query%';
```

**EDIT**

Your second query has an extraneous parenthesis.

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM   orders o 
WHERE  o.id in 
       ( SELECT order_id 
         FROM   order_items 
         WHERE  order_items.service_id In
                ( SELECT id 
                  FROM   services 
                  WHERE  name like '%query%'))
   OR  o.id in 
       ( SELECT order_id 
         FROM   order_items 
         WHERE  order_items.customer_id In
                ( SELECT id 
                  FROM   customers 
                  WHERE  name like '%query%')) 
   OR o.id in
       ( SELECT order_id 
         FROM   order_items 
         WHERE  order_items.cloth_id In
                ( SELECT id 
                  FROM   cloths 
                  WHERE  name like '%query%'));
```

However, for clarity, you could push the OR inside the subquery:

```
SELECT o.id 
FROM   orders o 
WHERE  o.id in 
       ( SELECT order_id 
         FROM   order_items 
         WHERE  order_items.service_id In
                ( SELECT id 
                  FROM   services 
                  WHERE  name like '%query%')
            OR   order_items.customer_id In
                 ( SELECT id 
                   FROM   customers 
                   WHERE  name like '%query%') 
            OR   order_items.cloth_id In
                 ( SELECT id 
                   FROM   cloths 
                   WHERE  name like '%query%'));
```

Comment: thanks for your response, pls see what i tried again if it makes some sense, also make small corrections to the tables

Comment: I have fixed your second query, too. However, as a word of advice, don't rely on people on stackoverflow to count parentheses for you... Your second query seems fine on the first look, but I cannot judge whether it selects what you want (because I know neither your use case nor your schema). And I will not do all your work ;)

Comment: cani ask what tool you use for sql queries, so you use a software that builds queries

Comment: I just use a simple text editor (usually Emacs or Notepad++) to work on SQL queries. In my view, visual query builders are not really useful for non-trivial queries.